# Selenium not waiting for file to download and continues ignoring while loop

Tags: python, selenium, file, download

I'm writing a script to download some youtube videos into mp3 and want the code to start a single download and after that continue with the other and the other and so on. The thing is, after the first download finishes, something brokes and starts to skipping download and not waiting for the download to finish to continue. Here's what I wrote, hope you can help me:

```
    for names in items:
    stringName = "".join(names)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + stringName)
    time.sleep(6)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='video-title']").click()
    songLink = driver.current_url
    driver.get("https://ytbmp3.club/")
    driver.find_element_by_id("dlURL").send_keys(songLink, Keys.RETURN)


    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='embed-responsive-item']").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    wait = True
    while (wait == True):
        for fname in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\sdf\\Desktop\\pruebatelgspo'):
            if ('.crdownload') in fname:
                print('downloading files ...')
                time.sleep(10)
            else:
                wait = False
    print('finished downloading all files ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (wait == True):
    for fname in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\sdf\\Desktop\\pruebatelgspo'):
        if ('.crdownload') in fname:
            print('downloading files ...')
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            wait = False
```

This is the troublemaker section:

You first set `wait = True` and initiate the while loop to continue if `wait == True`. Now you go through all the filenames in your given directory and check one by one if `.crdownload`is in the name.
Now occurs the problem: The first time your script runs through the else-section `wait` is set to `False`, which will result in the while-statement not being fulfilled and hence cancelling.

Therefore, the while-loop will be left even if there are still files with `.crdownload` in the directory, just because you ran "through" the else-block.

---

A suggestion to fix this issue:

```
while wait == True:
    if any('.crdownload' in n for n in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\sdf\\Desktop\\pruebatelgspo'):
    continue
else:
    break
```

You could also replace `break` with `wait = False`, depending on which syntax better suit your future needs in the software you're writing.

Comment: I don't know if something else should be fixed, but I changed the False in the else statement to a True and now it won't even wait for the first download to complete

Comment: @MiguelArrieche I didn't say you should fix that to `True`. I just pointed out what causes the error, now you should modify it to your wish. Anyhow, I edited my reply and suggested something.